# Capture HTTP Request Body with Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests

Is there any way to capture Web Api Post request body with Selenium 4.3.0 and .Net6.0 ?

I am trying to get the response body after I sent this post request through UI.

The reason I want to intercept HTTP Api request payload is that we have implemented tinyMCE to our application. I want to add text to messageBody with TinyMCE functions used so I know tinyMCE functions are working as expected.
The way that I am doing is to send "one" with <Bold,Italic,Color ... etc>
[Message Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAFrs.png)

After I click to sendEmail I see that in POST request payload the message with HTML tags, so that`s the strategy that I am following to validate tinyMCE functions. I am trying to capture POST request payload and compare and validate with the one I had saved in my script.

[Post request Payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8pYY.png)

For this reason I am trying to intercept the post request payload.

I have tried:
driver=new ChromeDriver();

IDevlTools devTools = driver as IDevTools;

session= devTools.CreateDevToolsSession() --> this does not exist anymore

so this did not work..
Any ideas are appreciated!!!!

Comment: Can you please clarify why you need to read the request body? Typically Selenium is used to automate a user interface. It is not ideal/or even possible to test web API calls directly with Selenium. A different testing tool, like Postman, is a better fit.

Comment: I am trying to use tinyMCE functions and our additional functions on TinyMCE, I want to validate they are working as expected. I send the message to the other party and want to make sure they get it as it is. I do not want to connect framework to database so that`s why I want to validate through HTTP Post Request Body.

Comment: We are going to need a lot more information then. I'm still not understanding why you need to see request/response data. Why not look for some sort of visible change in the browser?

Comment: I have edited the post, I hope it`s more clear why I am trying to accomplish this...

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correct you need something like this:

```
IDevTools devTools = driver;
DevToolsSession session = devTools.GetDevToolsSession();
await session.Domains.Network.EnableNetwork();

session.DevToolsEventReceived += Session_DevToolsEventReceived;

 
static void Session_DevToolsEventReceived(object? sender, DevToolsEventReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.EventData);
}
```

You probably need to filter the events you received and the body you are looking for is the payload in the event data